# Topological sort, recursive, using generators

Tags: python, recursion, generator, topology

Data:  a dependency list, already verified to be acyclic.  So here, 'a' depends on 'b','c' (c depends on d), etc...

```
A = { 'a' :  dict(b=1, c=1),
    'c' : dict(d=1),
    'd' : dict(e=1,f=1,g=1),
    'h' : dict(j=1)
    }
```

I'd like to have a top-down, recursive solution to let's say, find the chain starting at 
'a':  a, c, d, e, g, f, b

So, right now (a non-generator solution):

```
def get_all(D,k):
    L = []
    def get2(D,k):
        L.append(k)
        for ii in D.get(k,[]):
            get2(D, ii)
    get2(D,k)
    return L
```

Obviously, this is pretty weak :)  I've been banging my head about how to how to get yields inside there, and I'd appreciate any py-foo y'all can bring to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_all(D, k):
    yield k
    for ii in D.get(k, []):
        for jj in get_all(D, ii):
            yield jj

A = { 'a' : dict(b=1, c=1),
    'c' : dict(d=1),
    'd' : dict(e=1,f=1,g=1),
    'h' : dict(j=1)
    }

for ii in get_all(A,'a'):
    print ii
```

Gives me

```
steve@rei:~/code/tmp
$ python recur.py
a
c
d
e
g
f
b
```

Comment: No problems :-) Maybe it is the case that I have had too much coffee today :P

Comment: Did someone say coffee!? :)   Good answer, freespace.

Comment: I believe this would not work in cases where multiple nodes point to the same node. {'a': dict(b=1), 'c': dict(b=1)}

Comment: How would it not work? With the data you have given, my algorithm yields b for the chain starting at a, which appears correct to me.

Answer (score 6):

Both answers give the same result, but if my reading of the question is correct give the wrong answer to a simple alteration to the given graph - if you add a dependency on 'c' from 'b' (which doesn't introduce a cycle as the graph is directed) the output is: 
`a
c
d
e
g
f
b
d
e
g
f`

which isn't totally helpful. Try this small variation, which keeps track of which nodes of the graph have already been visited:

```
def get_all(D, k, seen=None):
    if not seen:
        seen = set( )
    if k not in seen:
        seen.add(k)
        yield k
        for ii in D.get(k, []):
            for jj in get_all(D, ii, seen):
                yield jj
```

Comment: So, the problem with this method is that the storage length again can balloon up to N, where N is the number of nodes in the graph.  It is a very useful variation though.  For this particular application I don't mind revisiting chains.